# In-flight update - How to make MSI wait for the executable to exit before updating?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to do an in-flight update in our app. That means, I'm downloading an update, calling `msiexec` and exit in a reasonable time (less then a second). The MSI does the update and resumes the transaction by calling the updated version with a token passed to it. This actually works fine if I don't update the main executable.

The problem I have is that even though the calling app exits fairly quickly and the MSI seems to need some time before it actually gets to update the file, the main executable's update is deferred. I'm passing `/noreboot` (and `/passive`) to `msiexec` but that means that the app is "repaired" when launched next time. However since the app can be invoked directly (not through shortcuts) it needs to be updated properly.

So the question is, how can I make the windows installer wait for my app to quit before it checks whether it is locked or not?

I'm thinking right now that I could pass a process id to the installer and have a custom action (dll?) that waits for this, but I would like to avoid this for two reasons: 1) The app is already out there and it won't pass the process id and 2) I would like to find a solution that does not require me to write a DLL, *if possible*.

I'm using WiX to create the MSI setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution is a little to pragmatic but instead of starting msiexec from your main executable you could write a little helper tool.

Your main executable would call this helper which sleeps for a second or two and then calls msiexec while your main application is closing.

Another way could be to make use of the Wix-Utils:

Reference the Util-schema in your namespace:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

and configure it to ensure that your application is closed:

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="MyApp.exe" RebootPrompt="no" />
```

For a full list of all options have a look at the documentation:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html